# Удалить строки, которые слишком похожи друг на друга, чтобы не дублировать друг друга

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

У меня есть [набор данных по объявлениям о недвижимости](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XUjqeXVgjZJ8jVNAn9MeIb9zHLhVj4mwRs-hk1P050o/edit?usp=sharing). Несколько линий примерно одинаковы, поэтому они полны дубликатов, которые не совсем одинаковые. Какие методы лучше всего подходят для удаления строк, которые слишком похожи, чтобы не дублировать друг друга?

Похоже на это:

```
    ID  URL CRAWL_SOURCE    PROPERTY_TYPE   NEW_BUILD   DESCRIPTION IMAGES  SURFACE LAND_SURFACE    BALCONY_SURFACE ... DEALER_NAME DEALER_TYPE CITY_ID CITY    ZIP_CODE    DEPT_CODE   PUBLICATION_START_DATE  PUBLICATION_END_DATE    LAST_CRAWL_DATE LAST_PRICE_DECREASE_DATE
0   22c05930-0eb5-11e7-b53d-bbead8ba43fe    http://www.avendrealouer.fr/location/levallois...   A_VENDRE_A_LOUER    APARTMENT   False   Au rez de chaussÃ©e d'un bel immeuble rÃ©cent,...   ["https://cf-medias.avendrealouer.fr/image/_87...   72.0    NaN NaN ... Lamirand Et Associes    AGENCY  54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2017-03-22T04:07:56.095 NaN 2017-04-21T18:52:35.733 NaN
1   8d092fa0-bb99-11e8-a7c9-852783b5a69d    https://www.bienici.com/annonce/ag440414-16547...   BIEN_ICI    APARTMENT   False   Je vous propose un appartement dans la rue Col...   ["http://photos.ubiflow.net/440414/165474561/p...   48.0    NaN NaN ... Proprietes Privees  MANDATARY   54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2018-09-18T11:04:44.461 NaN 2019-06-06T10:08:10.89  2018-09-25
```

Пока что я пытался сравнить описание:

```
df['is_duplicated'] = df.duplicated(['DESCRIPTION'])
```

И сравнить массив фотографий:

```
def image_similarity(imageAurls,imageBurls):
    imageAurls = ast.literal_eval(imageAurls)
    imageBurls = ast.literal_eval(imageBurls)
    for urlA in imageAurls:
        responseA = requests.get(urlA)
        imgA = Image.open(BytesIO(responseA.content))
        print(imgA)
        for urlB in imageBurls:
            responseB = requests.get(urlB)
            imgB = Image.open(BytesIO(responseB.content))    
            hash0 = imagehash.average_hash(imgA) 
            hash1 = imagehash.average_hash(imgB) 
            cutoff = 5

            if hash0 - hash1 < cutoff:
                print(urlA)
                print(urlB)
                return('similar')
        return('not similar')

df['NextImage'] = df['IMAGES'][df['IMAGES'].index - 1]
df['IsSimilar'] = df.apply(lambda x: image_similarity(x['IMAGES'], x['NextImage']), axis=1)
```

Comment: Для сравнения текстов можно попробовать применить алгоритм  Doc2Vec